# Api Platform filter with calculated column (i.e. geo distance)

Tags: api-platform.com

I have done already several different custom filters for Api Platform, however now I need another one and I am missing the right way how to do that. Basically the task is to sort items by geo distance from a given point and show the distance. This is quite easy in pure SQL (see e.g. https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-and-gis-an-example/), but it seems quite complicated inside Api Platform. 
Basically there are several tasks to do:

- add a custom filter to column with gps value, easy
- define starting location. Can be set as `order[gps]` value, easy, usually you do not need the opposite direction
- optionally filter all rows with max. distance, also easy SQL WHERE with variable. This one is described in comments here https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/382, https://gist.github.com/vincentchalamon/6afb137e8c2d1dec1d5a1978b45b64ec
- add new SELECT column with calculated distance. You can add calculated columns inside php entity or serializer or custom controller, but how to add it inside `Filter::filterProperty()`? If I try `$queryBuilder->addSelect()`, then query works, but it breaks the Serializer:

```
Notice: Undefined index: _links
in vendor/api-platform/core/src/Hal/Serializer/CollectionNormalizer.php (line 85)
                $data['_links']['item'][] = $item['_links']['self'];
```

- finally, if you have extra column in SQL, you can `addOrderBy()` by its value.
- then the question would be, how to get the extra column into the entity, if it is not always present in the query? (it is present only when sorting by distance).

Probably I can split it into two parts - keep `$queryBuilder` to make the sort only and calculate the distance for extra column once again in php serializer/controller, but this is quite inefficient for large datasets. (Anyway even doctrine would be calculating it three times again and again - count(), DISTINCT IDs a detail query)

Anyone used that already or has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a custom filter:

1. Calculate distance in meters
2. Filter based on radius (max distance)
3. Order by closest

As follows:

```
protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
{
    // otherwise filter is applied to order and page as well
    if ($property !== 'distance') {
        return;
    }

    [$lat, $lng, $radius] = explode(',', $value);

    // add distance in DQL based on filter location point
    $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
    $queryBuilder
        ->addSelect('(6371000 * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians('.$rootAlias.'.lat)) * cos(radians('.$rootAlias.'.lng) - radians(' . $lng . ')) + sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians('.$rootAlias.'.lat)))) AS distance')
        ->having('distance <= :radius')
        ->setParameter('radius', $radius)
        ->orderBy('distance')
    ;
}
```

---

For this to work you also need to add custom DQL functions for acos, cos, radians, sin:

Here's a link for Doctrine Extensions https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            numeric_functions:
                acos: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Acos
                cos: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Cos
                radians: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Radians
                sin: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Sin
```

Comment: Thanks, it is clear for simple queryBuilder. But inside Api platform's custom filter you cannot add column with addSelect (see error above "Undefined index: _links"). Even it works here, it probably either breaks serializer elsewhere or anyway this new column cannot be (conditionally) defined in entity and used for output data.

For now I have used two computations (one in orderBy inside custom filter and second again in entity during serialization). As the amount of rows is small (<1000) it works as ugly workaround, but the question is still the same - how to do that better in Api platform?

Comment: @JanStefanides it is indeed a custom filter for API Platform, I just updated the code snippet to include the full method filterProperty.
Note that the filter is "distance" and it has the 3 values separated by a comma e.g. 
LAT = 48.8797806
LNG = 2.343632
Radius = 2000 m
?distance=48.8707806,2.343632,2000

Comment: Thanks for adding, however at my instance addSelect() does not work with "Undefined index: _links" error above. Anyway, how to get then the addSelect() new column into API response? (to reuse the value once it is already calculated).  `api-platform/core v2.5.2, doctrine/orm v2.7.0, symfony/framework-bundle v4.3.8`