# check if select count value is null/empty query builder symfony

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

My query builder looks like this

```
 $qb
            ->select([
                'c.id as c_id',
                'c.name as c_name',
                sprintf('(SELECT COUNT(t) FROM %s t WHERE t.example = c.example) as t_total',
                    t::class),
                sprintf('(SELECT COUNT(z) FROM %s z WHERE z.example = c.secondExample) as z_total',
                    z::class),
            ])
            ->from(c:class, 'c')
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

is there any way to check that t_total and z_total is null? I don't want show this row only if t_total AND z_total is null/empty

Comment: Do you mean to use `HAVING` with `IS NOT NULL` conditions?  I'm not sure I follow your requirements and we don't a [mcve].

Comment: @mickmackusa this works perfect for me. thanks

Comment: I suppose this is a related demonstration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60056279/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @mickmackusa say

```
$qb->having('z_total IS NOT NULL OR t_total IN NOT NULL');
```

works the way i wanted